# How to replace last occurrence of double quotes in a string - PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell

How to replace last occurrence of double quotes (") with KKK in PowerShell?
INPUT

```
"ABCD"|"EFGH"|"IJK" "|"LMNO"|"PQRST"|"WXYZ"
```

OUTPUT

```
"ABCD"|"EFGH"|"IJK" "|"LMNO"|"PQRST"|"WXYZKKK
```

I have tried `-replace ('$"',"KKK")`

Comment: `-replace ('$"',"KKK")` -> `-replace '"$', 'KKK'`; in essence, you simply accidentally swapped `$` and `"` in your regex.

Comment: Thank you. Request to suggest on replacing "| with 'KKKK'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`LastIndexOf` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof) to find the last occurrence of a character or substring in a given string:

```
# define input variables 
$inputString = '"ABCD"|"EFGH"|"IJK" "|"LMNO"|"PQRST"|"WXYZ"'
$substitute = 'KKK'

# find last occurrence of "
$lastQuoteAt = $inputString.LastIndexOf('"')

# construct new string with substitute in place of "
$inputString.Substring(0, $lastQuoteAt) + $substitute + $inputString.Substring($lastQuoteAt+1)
```

---

Alternatively you can use the `-replace` regex operator:

```
$inputString -replace '"(?=[^"]*$)', $substitute
```

The regex pattern `"(?=[^"]*$)` describes exactly one `"`, but only if it's immediately followed by any number of non-`"`'s and the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods, depending on the nature of the string and your needs.

- if you are SURE the string ends with the `"` OR if there are characters after that you DO NOT care for(i.e.: trailing spaces), you can use `$InputString -replace '"[^"]*$', $SubstituteString`
- if there are(or might be) characters after the `"` you DO care to keep, @Mathias R. Jessen's  `$InputString -replace '"(?=[^"]*$)', $SubstituteString` is your answer
- to replace ALL the `"|`, use instead `$InputString.Replace('"|', $SubstituteString)`
- you can chain the methods, too:

  - `$InputString.Replace('"|',SubstituteStringOne) -replace '"(?=[^"]*$)', $SubstituteStringTwo`
  - `$InputString.Replace('"|',SubstituteStringOne) -replace '"[^"]*$', $SubstituteStringTwo`

  (there is a regex that does everything at once, no doubt, but for the moment this seems more readable)